# UITableView to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
if ([cell.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]]) {
// Do something 1
} else {
// Do something 2
}
```

Can this code be converted to for UIIScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends, do you have a pointer to the item inside of the scrollView you want to co something with. If so you could change it like so (assuming all subviews of the scrollview are  UIImageViews):

```
for (int i = 0; i < [scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]]) {
        // Do something 1
    } else {
        // Do something 2
    }
}
```

Comment: here: `viewForItemAtIndex` - is this it?

Comment: You dont really tell HOW you know which cell to use.

Comment: I have 75 images, that whenever an UIScrollView stops for example image 1 it will do action 1.

Comment: So you want to do an action for each and every one of those images? If so you could do a simple for loop and iterate thru all of them.